# Kafka producer producing message but consumer not consuming using Python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am working with AWS EC2 instance. I am able to produce and consume data normally with kraft in terminal from my ubuntu 22.04 using ssh. When I try to produce data using a python script to the same topic - topic name "demo_test", i am able to produce it but nothing is being consumed by the corresponding consumer script or the terminal.

When i try to produce to and consume from a topic in terminal, it is wrking fine but when i try to achieve the same thing using jupyter, it is not working.

I have created an EC2 instance on AWS and have installed java and kafka 2.12-3.3.6 on it and am connecting to the instance using ssh ubuntu terminal on virtualbox

I have written the following code using kafka-python in jupyter:

Producer code:-

```
import pandas as pd
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
import json

producer = KafkaProducer(
 bootstrap_servers=['50.19.162.182:9092'],
 value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')
)

print(producer)
# prints -> <kafka.producer.kafka.KafkaProducer object at 0x7f2e4c21a200>

producer.send('demo_test', value='{"hello":"World"}')
# prints -> <kafka.producer.future.FutureRecordMetadata at 0x7f2e4c7f05b0> as output
```

Consumer code:-

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from time import sleep
from json import loads
import json

consumer = KafkaConsumer('demo_test',
 bootstrap_servers=['50.19.162.182:9092'],
 value_deserializer=lambda v: json.loads(v.decode('utf-8'))
)

print(consumer)
# prints -> <kafka.consumer.group.KafkaConsumer object at 0x7faad50af160>

for c in consumer:
  print(c.value)
```

I am new to kafka so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thankyou very much @AdesojiAlu sir. I had problems with the security group configuration -. i was running my kafka server on private IP.
But can you please help me out on another thing: If there was an error with the security group, why was I anble to produce and consume data sent from terminal only. Is it because this is allowed from localhost irrespective of the private IP adderss?

Comment: yes you are correct, In contrast, when accessing the Kafka server from a different machine, the traffic has to go through the network, where the security group rules apply. Therefore, if the security group rules are not correctly configured to allow traffic from specific IP addresses or ranges, you might experience issues connecting to the Kafka server from remote producers and consumers.For ensuring that your Kafka server can communicate with remote producers and consumers, you should:
Ensure that the security group attached to your Kafka server allows inbound traffic on the port that Kafka